Arora and Barak: Exercise 0.2. (b)
I am reading Arora and Barak's book "Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach". I am doing exercise 0.2. (b): For each of the following recursively defined functions $f$, find a closed (nonrecursive) expression for a function $g$ such that $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, and prove that this is the case. (Note: Below we only supply the recursive rule, you can assume that $f(1) = f(2) = \cdots = f(10) = 1$ and the recursive rule is applied for $n > 10$; in any case, regardless of how the base case is defined it won't make any difference to the answer. Can you see why?)
(b) $f(n) = f(n-1) + n$.
Here's what I tried: Let $f(1) = c_1, f(2) = c_2, ..., f(N) = c_N$, where $N$ is a positive integer and $c_1, c_2, ..., c_N$ are real numbers. For $n > N$, $f(n) = f(n-1) + n$. Therefore,
$$f(N+1) = f(N) + (N+1) = c_N + (N+1),$$
$$f(N+2) = f(N+1) + (N+2) = c_N+(N+1)+(N+2),$$
$$f(N+3)=f(N+2)+(N+3)=c_N+(N+1)+(N+2)+(N+3),$$
...,
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+n$$
$$=f(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$
$$=f(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$
$$=\cdots$$
$$=f(N+1)+(N+2)+(N+3)+\cdots+n$$
$$=c_N+(N+1)+(N+2)+(N+3)+\cdots+n$$
$$=c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}.$$
Now we want to prove that $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, i.e., $c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}=\Theta(n^2)$. It is equivalent to prove that "$c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}=O(n^2)$ and $n^2=O\left(c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}\right)$".
First, we want to prove that $c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}=O(n^2)$. It is equivalent to prove that there exists a constant $c$ such that $c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}\leq c \cdot n^2$ for every sufficiently large $n$. The above inequality can be rewrittent as:
$$\frac{c_N}{n^2}+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2n^2} \leq c$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{n^2+n-N(N+1)}{2n^2}+\frac{c_N}{n^2} \leq c$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{N(N+1)}{2n^2}+\frac{c_N}{n^2} \leq c$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \leq c.$$
When $n \geq N+1$,
$$\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N+1}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2n}\leq\frac{1}{2(N+1)},$$
$$n^2 \geq (N+1)^2 \Rightarrow \frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \leq \frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}.$$
Let
$$c = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}.$$
We can conclude that there exists a constant $c = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}$ such that $c_N + \frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2} \leq c \cdot n^2$ for every $n \geq N+1$.
Second, we want to prove that
$$n^2 = O\left(c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}\right).$$
It is equivalent to prove that there exists a constant $c$ such that
$$n^2 \leq c \cdot \left[ c_N + \frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2} \right]$$
for every sufficiently large $n$.
The above inequality can be rewritten as
$$\frac{n^2}{c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2}} \leq c$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2n^2}{2c_N+(N+1+n)(n-N)} \leq c$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2n^2}{n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N} \leq c.$$
I don't know how to continue. Any comments and answers are welcome.

Invert $\frac{2n^2}{n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N} \leq c$ to be $\frac{n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N}{2n^2} \geq 1/c$, and then continue similarly to your first part

To EnEm: Thank you for your comment. I will try it.

Invert
$$\frac{2n^2}{n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N} \leq c \tag{1}$$ to be
$$\frac{n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N}{2n^2} \geq 1/c. \tag{2}$$
Equation (2) can be rewritten as
$$\frac{n^2+n-N(N+1)}{2n^2}+\frac{c_N}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{c}. \tag{3}$$
Equation (3) can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{N(N+1)}{2n^2}+\frac{c_N}{n^2} \geq \frac {1}{c}. \tag{4}$$
Equation (4) can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \geq \frac{1}{c}. \tag{5}$$
When $n \geq N+1$,
$$\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N+1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{2(N+1)} \tag{6}$$
and
$$n^2 \geq (N+1)^2 \Rightarrow \frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \leq \frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}. \tag{7}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{2c_N-N(N+1)}{2n^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2}. \tag{8}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2} \geq \frac{1}{c}. \tag{9}$$
Let
$$c = \left[ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(N+1)}+\frac{|2c_N-N(N+1)|}{2(N+1)^2} \right]^{-1}. \tag{10}$$
We can conclude that there exists a constant $c$ as shown in (10) such that
$$n^2 \leq c \cdot \left[ c_N+\frac{(N+1+n)(n-N)}{2} \right] \tag{11}$$
for every $n \geq N+1$. Q.E.D.

Equation (2) is not correct. Because $n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N$ may be less than zero, you cannot directly invert (1).

You can assume WLOG that $n$ is big enough for $n^2+n-N(N+1)+2c_N$ to be positive.

To @Li-yaoXia: Thank you for your comment.
